# Failed to load skin error on Gluon Project

Tags: css, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have a custom control `ChoiceTextField`, with the corresponding `ChoiceTextFieldSkin`.

```
protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new ChoiceFieldSkin<T, ChoiceTextField<T>>(this);
    }
```

The control is correctly displayed, although I get following `Exception`:

```
Failed to load skin 'com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.a.ap' for control ChoiceTextField[id=choiceCounter, styleClass=choice-field colored button flat]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

I can solve the error by setting the skin in the CSS file:

```
.choice-field{
    -fx-skin: "com.energymeter.control.skin.ChoiceFieldSkin";
}
```

But I wonder what is causing the `Exception`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Are you somehow extending Gluon Charm `TextField`?

Comment: No it's extending `Control` and delegating to Java `TextField`. (I could see the exception after I enabled Logging which I had disabled by `LogManager.getLogManager().reset()`

Comment: Why does your control shows `button` style class?

Comment: I added the `button style class, because I wanted to inherit the look. I wasn't aware that the style class skin would be loaded as well. Removing the button style fixed the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short snippet of code to create a view with a custom control:

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    setCenter(new StackPane(new ChoiceTextField()));
}

class ChoiceTextField<T> extends Control {

    public ChoiceTextField() {
        getStyleClass().add("button");
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new ChoiceFieldSkin<>(this);
    }
}

class ChoiceFieldSkin<T> extends SkinBase<ChoiceTextField<T>> {

    private final TextField textfield;

    public ChoiceFieldSkin(ChoiceTextField<T> control) {
        super(control);
        textfield = new TextField();

        getChildren().add(textfield);
    }
}
```

shows the same exception:

```
javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass
Failed to load skin 'com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.a.ap' for control ChoiceTextField@4fb753dd[styleClass=button]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:735)
```

If you have a look to the javadoc for `Control.createDefaultSkin()`:

> Create a new instance of the default skin for this control. This is called to create a skin for the control **if no skin is provided via CSS {@code -fx-skin}** or set explicitly in a sub-class with {@code  setSkin(...)}.

(bold is mine).

And when you set `getStyleClass().add("button")`, it turns out that Charm overrides the ButtonSkin to provide the ripple effect via CSS, so there you have your exception.

As you mentioned, this exception won't happen if you explicitly set the skin via CSS:

```
public ChoiceTextField() {

    getStyleClass().addAll("choice-field", "button");
        getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
} 


.choice-field {
      -fx-skin: '<package name>.ChoiceFieldSkin'
}
```

Comment: Good to know that exceptions on loading a skin only get logged, instead of being rethrown. I would never have noticed my mistake, if I had not switched on logging.